# Ubuntu 22.04 Wifi stopped working

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 22.04

Recently after an update the Wifi in my Ubuntu 22.04 stopped working. Looking at the UI it shows that it is connected to the Wifi but I cannot access the internet and don't get response when pinging anything.

I tried to connect via cable and with another USB Wifi dongle but neither was working.
Also I tried to downgrade to a previous version the kernel (5.13.0-46) but it didn't work.

Here some of my logs

dmesg

https://pastebin.com/xpp94z2L

ifconfig

```
wls1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
        inet6 fe80::7798:f81c:226d:15c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e8:b1:fc:21:af:2a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 314  bytes 70645 (70.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 66  bytes 9229 (9.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Content from /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo iface lo inet loopback auto wlan0
```

lshw -C network

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
       logical name: wls1
       version: 6b
       serial: e8:b1:fc:21:af:2a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-35-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode ip=192.168.5.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:33 memory:ed200000-ed201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
       logical name: enp60s0
       version: 10
       serial: ac:9e:17:98:9b:bc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-35-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ed104000-ed104fff memory:ed100000-ed103fff
```

lsmod output

```
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_comment             16384  8
ccm                    20480  6
isofs                  53248  1
rfcomm                 81920  16
uas                    28672  0
usb_storage            77824  3 uas
nf_conntrack_netlink    49152  0
xfrm_user              40960  2
xfrm_algo              16384  1 xfrm_user
xt_addrtype            16384  4
br_netfilter           28672  0
xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
xt_MASQUERADE          20480  5
xt_conntrack           16384  3
ipt_REJECT             16384  2
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_tcpudp              20480  9
nft_compat             20480  32
nft_chain_nat          16384  7
nf_nat                 49152  2 nft_chain_nat,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_conntrack          167936  4 xt_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_netlink,xt_MASQUERADE
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
nft_counter            16384  71
nf_tables             241664  210 nft_compat,nft_counter,nft_chain_nat
libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_tables
nfnetlink              20480  5 nft_compat,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables
bridge                299008  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
cmac                   16384  3
overlay               147456  0
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
nvidia_uvm           1200128  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      36864  1 intel_rapl_msr
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   151552  1
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
coretemp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
kvm_intel             364544  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
nvidia_drm             65536  6
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
kvm                  1003520  1 kvm_intel
nvidia_modeset       1150976  10 nvidia_drm
snd_hda_codec         155648  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
nvidia              39116800  528 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
iwlmvm                561152  0
aesni_intel           376832  8
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm               139264  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
btusb                  61440  0
uvcvideo              106496  0
mac80211             1228800  1 iwlmvm
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
rapl                   20480  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
drm_kms_helper        307200  1 nvidia_drm
snd_rawmidi            49152  1 snd_seq_midi
intel_cstate           20480  0
btintel                40960  1 btusb
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
iwlwifi               446464  1 iwlmvm
cec                    61440  1 drm_kms_helper
bluetooth             688128  43 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
rc_core                65536  1 cec
serio_raw              20480  0
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
videodev              249856  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_me                 40960  1
snd                   102400  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
joydev                 32768  0
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
input_leds             16384  0
efi_pstore             16384  0
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cfg80211              958464  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
at24                   24576  0
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                   135168  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
mac_hid                16384  0
asus_wireless          20480  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  3
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       122880  1 ipmi_devintf
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             49152  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
drm                   606208  10 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  9 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_CHECKSUM,xt_comment,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE
autofs4                49152  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     49152  0
hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
hid_generic            16384  0
mfd_aaeon              16384  0
asus_wmi               45056  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
usbhid                 65536  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                   147456  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
platform_profile       16384  1 asus_wmi
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ahci                   45056  4
psmouse               176128  0
r8169                  98304  0
i2c_i801               36864  0
libahci                45056  1 ahci
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
lpc_ich                28672  0
realtek                32768  1
xhci_pci               24576  0
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
wmi                    32768  3 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,asus_wmi,mfd_aaeon
video                  53248  1 asus_wmi
```

nmcli

```
DEVICE        TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION       
wls1          wifi      connected               ISKONOVAC-5cd075 
docker0       bridge    connected (externally)  docker0          
virbr0        bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0           
p2p-dev-wls1  wifi-p2p  disconnected            --               
enp60s0       ethernet  unavailable             --               
lo            loopback  unmanaged               --
```

rfkill shows that the device is not blocked

ping to 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9204ms
```

uname.txt

```
Linux fr-laptop 5.15.0-35-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 21 02:24:07 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am really not sure why this is happening as I to me it seems like everything is ok and kernel modules are loaded. (at least to me)

If there is anything relevant missing in debugging the issue let me know.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does did not work mean when you tried to use an older kernel? Some details please. What kernel are you running, what kernel did you try?

Comment: `inet 192.168.5.25` - does that reflect the router / gateway and netmask?

Comment: Sorry, I added now my `uname -a` and the previous kernel version 5.13.0-46. When I downgraded I experienced the same issue. Nothing changed. About 192.168.5.25, I don't think it is the gateway (I am not really experienced with networks) I checked on my other laptop and with `ip -r` and I get 192.168.5.1. Thanks

Comment: Check if  your router somehow "allow" or "block" 192.168.5.25, logged in on the wireless AP? Check wireless settings.

Comment: You have 192.168.5.**1** on another computer; **.1** is often the gateway, what IP does your router have; if it is set to be the same, you would have a problem there; the computer getting network packets that belong at the router.

Comment: Thanks Hannu, I checked on my router. I didn't see any block for 192.168.5.25. As far as I can see it is the DHCP lease for the laptop. 192.168.5.1 is the address of my router. I tried now to connect from the laptop to my hot spot mobile but still the same. On my other Linux business laptop Wifi works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I fixed the issue.
Iptables was blocking the traffic. That was caused by Nordvpn kill switch, which I tried once.
Restarting nordvpn and re-connecting resolved the issue.

Thanks everybody for the help.

Comment: Had you installrd Nordvpn or something ? I upgraged to 22.04 & had number of default upgrades & now am not able to access the outside net, though can access local. Also..... I ab able to access outside thru smartphone usb tethering. Could give me some suggestions ?

Comment: I had installed Nordvpn and was using it. For me it started working once I disabled iptables. You can try this to see if this is the issue. Here a link how to disable it. https://serverfault.com/a/129087/542298